# How does solidity handle mod 0?

Tags: solidity

Imagine you have a function like this:

```
function compute(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
  return a % b;
}
```

Does it revert when b is 0?

Comment: Related: [Why is n mod 0 undefined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516251/why-is-n-mod-0-undefined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered in the Solidity documentation.

From https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html#modulo:

> Modulo with zero causes a Panic error. This check can **not** be disabled through unchecked `{ ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

It reverts, but with INVALID opcode (similar to `assert`) rather than REVERT opcode (similar to `require`).

In order to impose the latter, you can add `require(b != 0)` prior to `return a % b`.

If `b` is a user-input value, then you **should** add this `require` statement.

If `b` is an internally-generated value in your system and you know that it is never supposed to be 0, then you **can** add `assert(b != 0)` prior to `return a % b`, or you can leave it as is (since, as mentioned above, `a % b` will yield the exact same behavior).

Comment: Just discovered an important implication of this. If you let Solidity handle mod 0, the contract call will consume all remaining gas. If you preemptively require the divisor not to be zero, which leaves remaining gas untouched.

Comment: This is why OpenZeppelin added a `mod` function in [SafeMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.0.2/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg: This implication is obvious from the answer, because it is well known that `require` (and more generally, the REVERT opcode) returns the remaining gas to the user, while `assert` (and more generally, the INVALID opcode) does not. Thus, as explained in my answer, you should use `require` (OZ function if you will), when dealing with user-input. That's also explained in my answer IMO (or at least implied by it).

Comment: For sure, but you're a seasoned Solidity engineer. Now the gas consumption implications are obvious to anyone stumbling upon this StackExchange thread.